# Find the path of a file from non working directory

Tags: java, file, vbscript

My code looks like:

```
File file = new File("src/STMInstall/script/install.vbs");
System.out.println("wscript"+" "+file.getAbsolutePath());
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript"+" "+file);
p.waitFor();
```

When I run the above piece of code from `c:\auto\src`. I get the following exception:

> Can't find a script file in C:\auto\src\src\STMInstall/script/install.vbs

How can I solve it? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide proper relative path like 'STMInstall/script/install.vbs' or the absolute path starting from 'C:\'. In case you want to run the code from anywhere, you should go with the absolute path.

```
File file = new File("C:\Users\Administrator\workspace\STM-Automation\src\STMInstall\script\install.vb‌​s");
System.out.println("wscript"+" "+file.getAbsolutePath());
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript"+" "+file);
p.waitFor();
```

Comment: I want this piece of code to run wherever i place my project and run it from anywhere. It should locate the file properly

Comment: Then you should prove the absolute path. That is, the path starting from "C:\".

Comment: Can you please give me an example or modify mine

Comment: Please tell me the path of install.vbs starting from the C directory

Comment: C:\Users\Administrator\workspace\STM-Automation\src\STMInstall\script\install.vbs. this is in eclipse project. But I am trying to run it from a different machine. from C drive

Comment: No, this won't pick up the data from other machine. In that case, you should do `scp`.

Comment: I guess you understood me wrong. Let me be brief it. I am running in a test machine. I have placed the source code under C:\STM-Automation. And ran the executable file from C:\STM-Automation\src\TestNG. The script file is located in C:\STM-Automation\src\STMInstall\script. Code is as mentioned in the question.   I want my code to execute from wherever I run my exe file. either from C driver or from desktop

Comment: The file is in the same machine in which the code is run?

Comment: Then the code in the answer should work. Please mark it correct if it works for you.

Comment: Can you please try "/" instead of "\" in the path? I am not on Windows, hence, not able to check the right one?

Comment: I tried changing doesn't work either. how does it even work when such path do not exist in the TEST MACHINE.

Comment: As you said, the code will be running in a machine where this path exists. Hence, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I used following code and it worked:

File file = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("STMInstall/script/install.vbs").toURI());